# Error Message: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SkipCertificateCheck'

Tags: python, powershell

I have tried google to find resolution of  issue  i am facing but cant find the same ..

I have list of powershell and python script  in my directory .My main python script creats a menu which asks user to select the choice and based on choice it  is calling powershell  or python file ..

[image]

below is the function which calls powershell script  if selected choice by user is a powershell file ..

```
 def run_script(script_name, f5_ip, username, password):
        script_path = f"{script_name}"
        if script_path.split(".")[1] =="ps1":
            args = ["-F5_IP", f5_ip,"-Username", username, "-pass",password]
        # call powershell files
            subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe","-executionpolicy" ,"bypass", "-File", script_path] + args)
        else:
            #call python files .
            subprocess.run(["python", script_path, f5_ip, username, password])
```

I am able to run and execute powershell files individually with no certificate error .. but when i trigger from python  i am getting below  error ..

my powershell code which calls the API :

```
#----Virtual servers

   try {
    
   # Base URL for iControl REST API
$URI = "https://$f5_IP/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/stats"



# Create authorization header
$authHeader = $Username + ":" + $Pass
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic "+ [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$authHeader"))
}

**$vsstats=@(Invoke-RestMethod  -URI $URI -Headers $Headers -Method Get -ContentType application/json -SkipCertificateCheck**)
```

[image]

I have tried all the possible code adding to my powershell file to skip certificate warnings  like

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
 }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

I have no idea how to resolve this  as i am just passing arguments to my powershell files and i am able to run each powershell individually successfully..

Please help here .. I am using  powershell 7   and python 3.1

[image]

Comment: Are you certain Python is using the PS version you think it is?  If this works by running it directly in PS7, but fails via Python because 'SkipCertificateCheck' is missing, it looks like it is actually invoking _Windows PowerShell_ (i.e. v5.1), as that parameter does not exist in that version: [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2#-skipcertificatecheck)

Comment: Replace the call to "powershell.exe" with "pwsh.exe" to run PowerShell 7, which is required to use parameter `-SkipCertificateCheck`, as @boxdog pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Zett42 .

i Changed from powershell.exe to pwsh.exe to point to powershell 7 instead of powershell 5.1 to reslove the same ..